# How to pick a random number from a set of numbers in simulink?

Tags: matlab, random, simulink

I want to pick a number from a set of number, i.e [1011, 1001, 1111, 1101, 0011] once at the beginning of each simulation. But i am not getting any help from the random number generator blocks. MATLAB code works in this case, so I've used matlab fuction block to run the code in simulation. But the code keeps running and generating value. Is there any fix to this?

The code I'm using in the fuction block is:

numbers = [1011, 1001, 1111, 1101, 0011, 0101, 1100];
% Generate a random index
index = randi(length(numbers));
% Display the random number
data=(numbers(index));

tried many things. but either it is generating frequent random values or showing same value in every simulation from the set of numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Below are two options for generating a varied random number for the first timestep of a sim. You might want to change the MATLAB function to output your indexed array value, or just to use `randi` instead of `rand` and output the random index itself. I'll leave the adaptation to you...

---

There are a couple of random number generator blocks in Simulink, but they use a seed so that the simulations are consistent run-to-run. If you want a different value each time you run the simulation then I think you'll need to use a MATLAB function block, since then you can use `rng('shuffle')` to start from a random seed each time.

[image: simple model]

```
function y = fcn()
    % MATLAB function block code for Simulink model with random seed
    rng('shuffle');
    y = rand();
```

As you say, this will generate a new random number each timestep.

You can change the behaviour so the random number is only generated once at the start of the simulation in two ways, **either**:

- Using a persistent variable in the above function so it's only set once.

  The Simulink model is unchanged, but the MATLAB function code becomes:

  ```
  function y = fcn()
      % MATLAB function block code for Simulink model with random seed
      % Use a persistent variable to only regen the random number at start
      persistent r 
      if isempty( r )
          rng('shuffle');
          r = rand();
      end
      y = r;
  ```
- **Or** using an enabled subsystem which only runs on the first timestep. This is a nice option because it's easier to add other conditions in the simulation to trigger an update on the random output.

  You would use the original MATLAB function code (without the persistent variable) but put the block into an Enabled Subsystem. The input to the enabled port is a constant 0, so never enabled, but via a Memory block which has an initial value of 1. This means on the first timestep the Memory's initial value of 1 is used and the subsystem runs, but for all future timesteps the subsystem is disabled. The default output behaviour for an enabled subsystem is to hold the previous output, so the initial random number will persist. As mentioned, you can make the enabled logic more complex if you ever want to trigger an update.

  [image: enabled subsystem]

  [image: enabled subsystem parent]